# How do I avoid a conversion operator to invoke the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, conversion-operator

As part of an optimization/cleanup pass, I'm trying to understand how to reduce temporary copies. While doing this I noticed that a conversion operator invoked my class's copy-constructor which otherwise can be avoided.

```
struct CSetViewer
{
    int s;
    CSetViewer(int size) : s(size) {}
    CSetViewer(const CSetViewer &) = delete;
    CSetViewer &operator=(const CSetViewer &) = delete;
    CSetViewer(CSetViewer &&) = delete;
    CSetViewer &operator=(CSetViewer &&) = delete;

};

struct CSet
{
    operator CSetViewer() { return {1}; }
    CSetViewer GetSetViewer() { return {1}; }
};

void testSet(const CSetViewer &set) {}

void main()
{
    CSet set;
    testSet(set.GetSetViewer());
    testSet(set); // Error: attempting to reference a deleted function
}
```

In the following code, the first call to testSet compiles fine, but the second seems to want to invoke the copy constructor.

Adding:

```
void testSet(CSetViewer &&set) {}
```

Makes the code compile (VS 2017), but I really don't understand why as I thought that const-reference version would suffice in this situation.

How is the conversion operator different from the GetSetViewer function? Can I make the code above work with the conversion operator without invoking the copy or move constructor?

Comment: What C++ standard are you using (on MSVC, this is the `/std:` flag)?

Comment: GCC accepts this code (well, `s/void main/int main/`) as of c++11: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37ea3caefd1d9aae. So does clang: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf791bd7b941d98.

Comment: Interesting. All three available language standards (14/17/latest) fails in VS 2017.

Comment: indeed: https://godbolt.org/z/oDeboI looks like a compiler bug

Comment: related: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/402870/guranteed-copy-elision-failing-on-conversion-opera.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known bug of Microsoft Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/402870/guranteed-copy-elision-failing-on-conversion-opera.html). A bug report has been filed the 2018-11-12. No news from there.

Comment: Wow. That was some quick work. And it was the last place I would have looked. :)

Comment: Since the introduction of the developer community, bugs flow more quickly from users to the dev team.